# jquery css wont work with ajax

Tags: jquery, css, json

I am making a list from ajax and that part works just fine. I am also checking the sreenwidth and changing the width of some of my divs accordingly but cant get it to work when I use ajax...

Here is what i do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    swidth = screenwidth - 20;

    $("#thelist li").css("width", swidth+"px");

    $.getJSON('linktomyphppage.php', function(data) {

        var array = [];

        $.each(data, function (i, val){

            array.push($("#thelist").append("<li>"+val.fname+" "+val.lname+"</li>"));

        });

    });

});
```

My json looks like this:

```
[{"fname":"Peter","lname":"Hanson"},{"fname":"Michael","lname":"Bird"}]
```

The json part works just fine, but it is like it doesn't get the CSS part at all. If I do it like this it works, but then I don't use the json:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    array.push($("#thelist").append("<li>"+val.fname+" "+val.lname+"</li>"));

}
```

Hoping for help, and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I guess it is because you are using `#thelist li` before it was created.. Just change the position of jQuery CSS and place it at last..

Comment: can you build a JsFiddle with an example? what does the console.log with swidth show? maybe you aren't getting a valid response from swidth? and you also should ```var swidth``` also I don't think this is the problem

Comment: `css()` adds the `style` attribute to the elements so the new elements won't have it. Just move the css part to the end of your json request callback.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the timing dependencies of setting the CSS via script, just define a rule:

```
#thelist li {
    position: relative;
    right: 20px; 
}
```

In general, it's much preferable to just write CSS, rather than trying to build it dynamically and sprinkle commands to insert it throughout your code. In the ideal case, the script would do nothing but add/remove classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    swidth = screenwidth - 20;

    $.getJSON('linktomyphppage.php', function(data) {
        var array = []
            html  = '';

        $.each(data, function (i, val){
            html +=  "<li style='width:"+ swidth +"px;'>"+val.fname+" "+val.lname+"</li>";
        }

        $("#thelist").append(html);
    });
});
```

You should set the style to the `li` AFTER it has been created.

And doing a single `append` is a good practice as multiple DOM manipulation is slow(relatively) and more resource intensive.